# Import Error - Tensorflow Installation

Tags: tensorflow

I just installed Tensorflow and the short program that I was supposed to use in order to validate my installation works fine.

My editor though has a red underline under the import command in the

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

When I hover my mouse over it I get the the error message

```
[pylint] E0401: Unable to import 'tensorflow'
```

I want to point out that when I compile the program I don't get that error.

Why is that happening when obviously tensorlow works fine? How can I fix that?

Comment: How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: @DinushaDilanka I followed the official instructions of this link https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux for Python 3.n in Virtualenv.

Comment: What is your editor?

Comment: @DinushaDilanka Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Did you set python interpreter correctly?

Comment: @DinushaDilanka The program runs as it should without producing this error in the terminal.

Comment: This is things dude, linux has different python interpreter. Make sure which interpreter has been used to install tensorflow.

Comment: @DinushaDilanka How do I do that?

Comment: First you have to check which python interpreter support for tensorflow when you run code in terminal. Then set same interpreter into Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @DinushaDilanka I did it. That is not the problem.

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: Are you using anaconda 3, python 2  or python 3?

Comment: I checked what interpreters I have installed and I checked those that are used by the VS Code.  As I mentioned the program runs fine, the only issue is that the VS Code thinks that something is not ok. Also I only use Python 3 and I made sure I installed Tensorflow using that version. Also I am sure that VS Code uses that version too.

Comment: Is this way you run python code in terminal `python3 test.py` ?

Comment: @DinushaDilanka Of course.

Comment: Check with this `python2 test.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167854/discussion-between-dinusha-dilanka-and-adam).

Comment: Solution in [here](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/)

Comment: @DinushaDilanka The solution is in the other link.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dinusha Dilanka, the answer to that question was that I had to manually specify an interpreter.

This can be achieved by selecting the Settings and creating, or modifying, the entry `python.pythonPath` as follows.

```
"python.pythonPath": "PATH/python"
```

for Linux, or

```
"python.pythonPath": "PATH/python.exe"
```

for Windows.